# Reporting java exceptions in jira automaticly

Tags: java, reporting, jira

I'm developing web application using Spring roo (mvc), this application is the ERP system. I plan to use Jira as my issues reporting system. My question is, if is there any solution that will help me report exceptions thrown in my web application in jira automaticly?

I thought about creating some script that will be scanning logs and creating issues in jira. What do you think about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LogDigger library to solve this problem. 
Below I attached a link to the tutorial, where it is described how to integrate LogDigger with Zendesk, but you can analogously integrate LogDigger with Jira using this REST API.

http://mobeelizer.com/blog/2013/01/how-to-integrate-logdigger-with-zendesk-quick-tutorial/